# NumericUpDown in GridCell - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I have a grid with a collection of "ItemPresupusto". I need to add a NumericUpDown (by mahApps) to be able to modify the "Cantidad" property of each "ItemPresupuesto" and every time I modify that property, I need to update data in the UI. I've tried everything, but I can not do it. Im use MVVM Light Some help. Thank you!

**.XAML**

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Articulos}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cantidad" MinWidth="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mahApps:NumericUpDown Minimum="1"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Value="{Binding Cantidad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel

```
public class PresupuestosViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     public IEnumerable<ItemPresupuesto> Articulos => new ObservableCollection<ItemPresupuesto>(Presupuesto.Items);
}
```

Class

```
public class ItemPresupuesto: EntidadBase

    {

        public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }

    }

public class Presupuesto : EntidadBase
{

    public virtual List<ItemPresupuesto> Items { get; }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you "can't do"?

Comment: @mm8 Hello !, I need to update the UI when I modify some value of some NumericUpDown

Comment: What does "UI" means in this case, i.e. what control do you need to update?

Comment: It is a label, which contains a mathematical operation. I.e. (Cantidad * Precio = Total) Amount * Price = Total. "Cantidad" is the property that I modify with the NumericUpDown

Comment: Maybe adding `{get; }` to your `Articulos` Property.

Comment: @Kirenenko Yes, I think the problem is here "public IEnumerable<ItemPresupuesto> Articulos => new ObservableCollection<ItemPresupuesto>(Presupuesto.Items);" , but I do not know how to solve it, I tried that and I did not get it to work.

Comment: `private IEnumerable<ItemPresupuesto> _Articulos = new ObservableCollection<ItemPresupuesto>(Presupuesto.Items); public IEnumerable<ItemPresupuesto> Articulos{ get {return _Articulos; } }`. Or something like that, I dont have an editor at this moment.

Comment: In what class is the Precio property defined?

Comment: @mm8 in ItemPresupuesto class

Comment: @Kirenenko I tried that, the problem is the "set" and the INotifyChange interface, changing the value of "Cantidad" does not activate RaicePropertyChange and I can not do what I want.

Comment: The ItemPresupuesto  class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise change notifcations then. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemPresupuesto class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged and interface and raise change notifications for the source property that is bound to the control that you want to refresh whenever the Cantidad or Prico properties are set:

```
public class ItemPresupuesto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _cantidad;
    public decimal Cantidad
    {
        get { return _cantidad; }
        set { _cantidad = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Total)); }
    }

    private decimal _prico = 1;
    public decimal Prico
    {
        get { return _prico; }
        set { _prico = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Total)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public decimal Total => _prico * _cantidad;
}
```